# Как правильно закрыть доступ к ЮРЛ в vestaCP через nginx?

Tags: nginx, vesta

Хочу закрыть доступ к **phppgadmin**. 
Пробовал разные конструкции наподобие этой

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  *.beta.host1.com, *.host2.com;

    location /phppgadmin/ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Но ни один из вариантов не сработал. Хотя **restart nginx** срабатывает без ошибок . А как мне указать, что это должно срабатывать для всех хостов? У меня он не один. Также мне нужно закрыть доступ не только к **/phppgadmin/** , но и ко всем дочерним адресам, например: **/phppgadmin/sub/ind.php** . Как это правильно реализовать?

Или может просто какой-то порт закрыть нужно?

Comment: похоже никак. в отдельный файл, а [потом инклуд в каждый сервер](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572448/2101808).

Comment: @eri , я пробовал и в отдельный сервер. Тоже ошибки не вылетают при рестарте веб-сервера, но у меня такое ощущение, этот локейшн просто не выполняется. Подскажите, может что-то еще не так в логике? Как задать локейшн для всех вложенных в /phppgadmin/ ?